# How to manually create a database file in android which could be used with SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to create a database  with 3 tables manually and include that file to my android app.
Is this possible. how?

Comment: The emulator has allows full access to the file system however, in theory, the file may not be binary compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Open terminal and follow the commands.

```
$ adb shell
# cd data
# cd data
# cd com.testapp  // your apps package.
# mkdir databases
# cd databases
# sqlite3
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

here you can create tables and can use as normal sql console.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create the database manually with [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/). Then you can copy it to emulator/device.